# Jquery .css() method not working with css functions

Tags: jquery, css, 3d, transform

Why is this:
`$("#bottom").css({"transform":"rotateX ("+rotation[0][0] + "deg)"});` not working?

rotation[0][0] is defined, and  I can change any other propriety (background-color, for example) so how do I rotate an element along his X axis with Jquery?
I'm using chrome, but I also tried with -webkit-transform.

Comment: inspect element does query add transform on inline or use `webkit-transform` instead transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have a space between `rotateX` and the first open bracket.

Change `"rotateX ("`:

```
$("#bottom").css({"transform":"rotateX ("+rotation[0][0] + "deg)"});
```

To `"rotateX("`:

```
$("#bottom").css({"transform":"rotateX("+rotation[0][0] + "deg)"});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/k2vaE/).

Comment: Oh, God. Can't believe it was something THAT stupid.